# Revel session clustering with redis

Tags: go, redis, revel

while in crystal#kemal, i have before_all method that will be a gateway of request (and for auth check)

```
before_all do |env|
  # go to /login if user doesn't have cookie (set cookie on login)
  if env.request.path != "/login"
    if env.request.cookies.has_key?("guid") == false
      env.redirect "/login"
    else
      user_guid = env.request.cookies["guid"].value
      # if in redis is logged, but not in the app
      if is_logged_in(user_guid)
        if !is_logged(env)
          app_sess_set(env, user_guid)
        end
      else
        env.redirect "/login"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

is revel has method like `before_all`, and can i do like kemal do ?

Answer (score 0):

http://revel.github.io/manual/interceptors.html

```
func (c App) SessionProcess() revel.Result {
    # do action
    return nil
}

func init() {
    revel.InterceptMethod(App.SessionProcess, revel.BEFORE)
}
```